# More than one resource for tx_news TYPO3

Tags: typo3, tx-news

i have more then one news resource folder in my typo3. My question: Can i use all of them in tx_news?

I want to build a news summary page of all these folders.

Thank you for your help!

Owi

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh ... Sorry!
Yes - You can use more then one sysfolder with news storage in one news plugin.
I was blind! You can select more then one source folder in the plugin config.